# How to add a random string using a package from backend in loopback nodejs mongodb model for post method in an endpoint

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopback4

So i have this endpoint created using loopback nodejs and it's post endpoint. Various fields are obtained from request itself but i want to generate a particular field containing random string from the backend itself whenever this post endpoint is invoked. Since i cant use the json file for installing package and creating random string. what could be done?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Since i cant use the json file for installing package and creating random string."? A LoopBack 4 app is like any other Node.js app; you can install other dependencies and modify the response in the controller before returning it.

Comment: So its based on persistent Model right and the mongo db model consists of both .json and .js file for a particular thing. The model is generally written in json but js is kept empty so I wasnt sure how to put the randomly generated string value in the json file. Maybe I m not sure,im new to loopback. Could you explain how to install and use a dependency

Comment: Models are defined in `*.model.ts` files which are Typescript files. The only JSON file in a LoopBack 4 application was the datasource configuration. But even that has been removed in favour of a Typescript file.

Installing and using dependencies are, for all intents and purposes, identical to how it's done in other Node.js apps. LoopBack 4 is a Node.js framework and it does not prevent you from doing a normal `import`.